# Take away bottom border before and after transition

Tags: css, less, border, transition

I have an on click dropdown menu thats animated on height, however, it has a 2px border and the border always appears when the menu is closed. Basically, it shows a little 2px strip where the menu would come out. I'm working in local, so its a bit hard to send all the code, but it's something like this:
(user__nav is a ul)

```
.user__nav {
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        border: 2px solid #2D3E65;
        border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.7s;


        ul>li {
            padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
            a {
                color: #2D3E65;
                font-weight: 500;
            }
            &:hover {
                background-color: #2D3E65;
                a {
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }
            &:last-child {
                border-radius: 0 0 9px 9px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when the element is clicked, I apply the following class to it:

```
.profile-transition {
max-height: 170px !important;
}
```

I also tried taking out the border from .user__nav {} and putting it in profile-transition but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
.profile-transition:before {
border: 2px solid #2D3E65;
}

.profile-transition:after {
border: 2px solid #2D3E65;
}
```

Anything would help! Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered playing with setting the box-sizing to border-box? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing not sure if this will fix it, but it might be a step in the right direction

Comment: I'll give it a shot ^_^ I'll let you know

Comment: no cigar, I did manage to do play with last child border, and no bottom border on the main ul